# How can I know whether automatic batching has been enabled in production

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, new-operator, setstate

Some info on the environment:

```
SDK Version: 48
Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): Android/iOS
react: 18.2.0, react-native: 0.71.4
Expo Workflow: managed 2.28
```

React new architecture and automatic batching have been available for react/react-native versions (mentioned in 3 above). Yet not available in Expo Go (4 above).

I’m interested in "automatic batching” since I have many setState used in my components.
My test results on rendering performance tell me below differences:

```
Expo Go - test environment (slow, and no automatic batching, render on every setState)
The app built - production environment (fast, just 30% time of that used in Expo Go)
```

But I don’t know whether “automatic batching” has been enabled in case 2 above.
Or whether faster rendering is because of automatic batching or new architecture…or because of some other reasons?

Does anybody know or with some advice to share?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Had the same question today. Did you find out something about this?